# How to print a variable in a txt file with Python 3

Tags: python

I have been searching online, but have not found any solution.

Here is my text file:

> I want x cookies
>   He wants y cookies

I want the python script to export the value in x and y from the user input.
Here is the script:

```py
xcookies = input("How much cookies do you want?") 
ycookies = input("How much cookies does he want?")
```

I found some scripts online but I can never keep the text from the original text file and export variables in this text file.

Could anyone please help me with that?

Comment: Have you tried to search an answer in any search engine?

Comment: Seems you missed the [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) part of the tutorial. Please follow the link.

Comment: _I have been searching online, but have not found any solution._ That seems unlikely. _I found some scripts online but I can never keep the text from the original text file and export variables in this text file._ What? Please share exactly what you tried. _Could anyone please help me with that?_ Help you with what? You haven't specified what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will append your variables to the end of MyFile.txt, a txt file in the same directory as the python script.

```
# Open the text file
txt_file = open("MyFile.txt","a")

# Append new line
txt_file.write('\n')

# Append your variables
txt_file.write(xcookies + '\n')
txt_file.write(ycookies + '\n')

# Close file
txt_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you want to reach in your script.
Please make your question more concrete.

Anyway, you can use this as a guideline:
In order to read a text file and write to a text file, you can do the following:

```py
with open("path/to/file.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
```

Using that you are able to read to the content of the file and then parse it
(using `data.split()` or whatever you need).

After getting the desired input from the user,
you are able to write the content back to the file by doing the following:

```py
with open("path/to/file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(content)
```

Please refer to those tutorials:

- [The Python Tutorial - Input and Output](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)
- [Python for Beginners - Reading and Writing Files in Python](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python)